# Altair - sorting continuous time axis daily data by month (Jun-May instead of Jan-Dec)

Tags: python, altair, vega

**Significantly Edited for clarity and with @jakevdp commentary/answer in mind**

Problem: plotting a timeseries of data (aggegated as monthdate) where the x-axis is months Jan-Dec and each year of data is a separate color. But instead of Jan-Dec, sort the axis from June-May (scientifically this is because winter is the season of interest and would like it to be in the center of the plot).

*Initial question was unclear* and helpful solution pointed out differences between ordinal and temporal encoding as well as sorting vs axis formating

```
#produces plot desired but with jan-dec range
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='M', periods=50),
    'value': range(50)
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('month(date):O'),
    y='value:Q',
    color=alt.Color('year(date):N')
)
```

[image: year_over_year]

and then sorting by month

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='M', periods=50),
    'value': range(50)
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('month(date):O',
            sort=['Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']),
    y='value:Q',
    color=alt.Color('year(date):N')
)
```

does achieve a plot style that I am going for

[image: year_over_year_shifted]

**Question**

Can this be done with monthdate aggregated data?

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='D', periods=500),
    'value': range(500)
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('month(date):O',
            sort=['Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']),
    y='value:Q',
    color=alt.Color('year(date):N')
)
```

with a monthdate aggregation instead of a month aggregation? so it isn't stair-stepped
[image: monthdate aggregation]

Comment: solution may still be a complex chart with axis formating

Answer (score 1):

For ordinal timeunits, you can sort the categories by listing the months in the desired order, as mentioned in the Vega-Lite [sorting docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html). For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2019-06-01', freq='M', periods=12),
    'value': range(12)
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('month(date):O',
            sort=['Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']),
    y='value:Q'
)
```

[image]

For temporal encodings, this approach does not work, because the data are treated as a continuous quantity. In this case (assuming the data is in the desired order), you might try using an [axis format](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/format.html) rather than a timeUnit:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('date:T', axis=alt.Axis(format='%b')),
    y='value:Q'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp - this provides some clarity.  As suspected - the data encoding as ordinal vs temporal was part of my issue...and appears it has to be aggregated by month (not monthdate) and the axis format methodology wont allow for a year over year plot.  I'll significantly refine my question based on this answer for clarity too